# should I get the same accuracy in the test set and the training set

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning, I have built a model that predicts if a client will subscribe in the following month or not. I got 73.4 on the training set and 72.8 on the test set. is it okay? or do I have Overfitting?

Comment: It's okay. They are not supposed to be same and this is not what overfitting is.

Comment: It's okay. They are not supposed to be same and this is not what overfitting is.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. 
**Overfitting happens when the accuracy in the training set in higher and the accuracy in the test set is lower** (with a marginal difference).

This is what overfitting looks like.

```
Train accuracy: 99.4%
Test accuracy: 71.4%
```

You can, however, increase the accuracy using different models and feature engineering

Answer (score 0):

We call it as over-fitting,If the accuracy of training data is abnormally higher **(greater than 95%)** and accuracy of test data is very low **(less than 65%)**.
In your case,both training and testing accuracy are almost similar.**So there is no over-fitting**.
Try for more test data and check whether the accuracy is decreasing or not.You can also try to improve the model by

1. **Trying different algorithms**
2. **Increasing the size of train data**
3. **Trying K-fold cross validation**
4. **Hyper parameter tuning**
5. **Using Regularization methods**
6. **Standardizing feature variables**